# Olympiad Geometry Problem

Tags: geometry

A point P in the interior of a convex polyhedron in Euclidean space is called a
pivot point of the polyhedron if every line through P contains exactly 0 or 2 vertices of the
polyhedron. Determine, with proof, the maximum number of pivot points that a polyhedron
can contain.